# check if a pin is long 4 or 6 digits or not

Tags: python, if-statement

I just started learning py and i tried to create a simple program that checks whether a pin is long a 4 or 6 digits or not, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
def validate_pin(pin):
    if len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6:
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

Comment: what's your input data? + capitalize True and False

Comment: it's on codewars so u don't have to enter one, u just gotta write the function

Comment: Explain "doesn't work".How do you call this function and what error do you get?

Comment: Python has its booleans starting with a capital letter. So it must be `return True` and `return False`.

Comment: @NameError Unfortunately we're missing a working code example in the question. If the code after the function looks like `true, false = False, True; print(validate_pin(0))` or just `validate_pin()` there might be a different error. Without guessing one can't answer the question as it is.

Comment: What data type do you pass to *validate_pin()*? Is it a string? If it's an *int* how would you want to handle a PIN number of 0001?

Answer (score 1):

The value passed to *validate_pin()* would need to be of type *str* for this to make sense. Consider a PIN number of 0001. That's a valid PIN number but when expressed as *int* it isn't. Therefore:

```
def validate_pin(pin):
  return len(pin) == 4 or len(pin) == 6
```

Comment: Also, Olvin Roght, I guess you need to mention to check if `pin` contains only numbers using the string function `isnumeric()`.

Comment: @NameError That would be true in the real world but OP's question wasn't really about PIN numbers, it was about length - not content

Answer (score 0):

Python booleans are capitalized, so you have to change `true` to `True` and `false` to `False`

Comment: Other thing is, ou need to make sure the pin variable is a string. If it's an int it cannot parse the method len()

Comment: Actually, there's no need in this case to explicitly return either True or False